# Does the app login gets counted to get the "Fanatic" badge?

Tags: discussion

Definition as per the website:

**Fanatic**: Fanatic Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days. (Days are counted in UTC.)

Does the app login gets counted to achieve it?

If not then, what is the reason?

Comment: I was out of town because of the holidays and I made sure I logged in with the app or the mobile website and both didn't register in the fanatic counter so I am back to zero...